# How do i show a hidden div when a checkbox is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="name">

</div>   

<input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" />Couldn't find the Venue<br />
```

I can add an Id or class if i need to

I need to toggle between hide and show the div based on the whether clicked or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" class="toggler" cheked="checked" />
```

and without animation,

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(){
       $('div#name').toggle(this.checked);
   });
})
```

## [cool demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BbyJ5/)

this with a little animation

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {
           $('div#name').slideDown();
       } else {
           $('div#name').slideUp();
       }
   });
})​
```

## [cool demo too](http://jsfiddle.net/BbyJ5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

given your checkbox ID is myCB:

```
$("#myCB").click(function(){

if($("#name").is(":visible"))
{
  $("#name").hide();
}
else
{
  $("#name").show();
}

});
```

you can also check out the .toggle() function:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is ready to use and simple code**

```
$('input[name=myCB]').toggle(function() {
  $("#name").hide();
}, function() {
  $("#name").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="name">
my div text
</div>   

<input type="checkbox" name="myCB" id="myCB" value="A"/>Couldn't find the Venue<br />

<script>
$('#myCB').toggle(function() {
$('#name').hide()
}, function() {
$('#name').show()
});
</script>
```